# Using linked lists with boolean methods

Tags: java

I need to create a PhoneBook using a linked list that contains multiple boolean  methods.One of those is insert that is susposed to enter a new Person in the PhoneBook, if the Person already exists the method phonebook shouldnt change.I am having trouble implementing this method, particullarly at the part where I'm supposed to compare the name the user inputs, with the one that is already in the phonebook.This is my code

```
class PhoneBookList implements PhoneBook {
    private int size = 0;
    Node head;

    private static final class Node {
        final Person person;
        Node next;

        Node(Person person) {
            this.person = person;
        }
    }

    public boolean insert(Person person) {
        Node n = new Node(person); 
        Node p = head,prev = null;


        if(p == null) {
            head = n;
            size++;
            return true;
        }

        int comparison = p.name.compareTo(n.name);

        if(comparison < 0) {
            n.next = p;
            p = n;
            size++;// 
            return true;
        }

        if(comparison == 0) {
            return false;

        }

        Node current = p;
        while(current.next !=null && current.next.person < person) {
            current = current.next;
        }
        if(current.next !=null && current.next.person == person) {
            return false;

        }

        n.next = current.next;
    current.next = n;
        size++;
    return true;
    }
}
```

We have to explicitly use this compareTo method,and I cannot get it to work.Any guidance.Here are the errors:

```
PhoneBookList.java:25: error: cannot find symbol
                int comparison = p.name.compareTo(n.name);
                                                   ^
  symbol:   variable name
  location: variable n of type Node
PhoneBookList.java:25: error: cannot find symbol
                int comparison = p.name.compareTo(n.name);
                                  ^
  symbol:   variable name
  location: variable p of type Node
PhoneBookList.java:40: error: bad operand types for binary operator '<'
                while(current.next !=null && current.next.person < person) {
                                                                 ^
  first type:  Person
  second type: Person
                                                                 ^
  first type:  Person
  second type: Person
```

Thank you!

Comment: if you want to compare names why not use `equals()` and instead of checking name exist in insert method write a method for searching a name.

Comment: Hey thanks for the feedback, as I've said in the assignment we're told that we HAVE TO use this compareTo method

Comment: not working means are you getting any error with your code

Comment: Yes,exactly,getting this particular error: PhoneBookList.java:40: error: bad operand types for binary operator '<'
                while(current.next !=null && current.next.person < person) {
                                                                 ^
  first type:  Person
  second type: Person

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To check if person already exist in the list you need to loop through all the nodes in your list and comapre each person name in node with the name of the person you want to insert.

```
class PhoneBookList implements PhoneBook {
    private int size = 0;
    Node head = null;

    private static final class Node {
        final Person person;
        Node next;

        Node(Person person) {
            this.person = person;
        }
    }

    public boolean insert(Person person) {
        Node n = new Node(person); 
        Node p = head;

        if(p == null) {
            head = n;
            size++;
            return true;
        } else {

            Node temp = p;
            int comparison;
            while(temp.next != null) {
                comparison = temp.person.name.compareTo(person.name);
                if(comparison == 0){
                    return false;
                }
                temp = temp.next;
            }
            temp.next = n;
            size++;
            return true;
        }

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Some comments on your code:

1. It has some if's that should not be there, since they do not treat special cases.
2. It uses am operator of comparison for the class Person that, if you really have implemented, then there has no sense to use the compareTo method.
3. I leave you a new version much more concise, that only creates the new object when necessary.

If you have not implemented the comparison operator, then you should change a < b by a.name.compareTo(b.name) < 0.

```
class PhoneBookList implements PhoneBook {
    private int size = 0;
    Node head;

    private static final class Node {
        final Person person;
        Node next;

        Node(Person person) {
           this.person = person;
       }
    }

    public boolean insert(Person person) {
        Node p = head;
        while (p != null) {
            if (p.person > person) break;
            p = p.next;
        }
        if (p.person == person) return false;
        Node n = new Node(person);
        if (p != null) n.next = p.next;
        p.next = n;
        return true;
    }
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: `p.person > person` why you comparing objects

Comment: Hey thanks for your answer. I've tried compling this program and I still get the error bad operan for the if (p.person > person) line.

Answer (score 0):

So you do not have the comparison operator implemented. Then for helping you, I must know the Person class implementation. There, you have to put you operator.